# Creating Predicate in To-Many Relationship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, nspredicate

Say some Business can belong to several districts (given that different people call the same place differently).

Say I want to find businesses whose one of the district contain @"Mangga"

So Business have relationship called Districts to a bunch of District entity and each District contains an attribute called name

How would I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the `ANY` keyword:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY districts.name = 'Mangga'"];
```